# React renderToString not have data-react-checksum

Tags: reactjs, checksum, server-side-rendering, render-to-string

```
    // renderToString
try {
    initView = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={location} context={context}>
                {renderRoutes(routes)}
            </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
    console.log('lzr======');
    console.log(initView);
    console.log('lzr======');
}
```

with running this, get initView like below:

```
<div data-reactroot=""><div></div><div><div class="common-side-bar"><a href="/"><div class="bar-top"></div></a><div class="pandect"><span class="icon-pandest"></span>some thing</div><div class="menu"><ul style="width:180px" class="ant-menu ant-menu-inline ant-menu-dark ant-menu-root" role="menu" aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0"><li class="ant-menu-submenu-inline ant-menu-submenu"><div style="padding-left:24px" class="ant-menu-submenu-title" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="iot$Menu" aria-haspopup="true"><span><i class="icon-iothub common-icon">....
```

i did initView.indexOf('check') and get -1. can anyone give me a help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [pullrequest](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/10402) which removed the data-reactid and data-react-checksum.